# Macro to check and put the unique value in a cell from column range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am very new to macros.

I wanted to convert the following formula to macro

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,$A2)=1,"NA",$A2)
```

Where in the $B1 will be incremental and I will be printing the value in $B2.

The final output should look like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it you just don't want duplicates? Use a scripting dictionary.

```
Dim dict as Object
set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i as Long
For i = 2 to 9
   dict(cells(i,1)) = 1
Next
Dim dictKey as Variant
i = 1
For Each dictKey in dict.Keys()
   cells(i,2) = dictKey
   i = i+1
Next
```

Or at the end:

```
dim dictVal as string
For i = 2 to 9
  dictVal = cells(i,1)
  If Dict(dictVal).Exists Then
    cells(i,2) = cells(i,1)
  Else: cells(i,2) = "N/A"
  End if
Next
```

---

Or if you want the crude way to do it

```
Sub testing()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For i = 2 To 9
        With Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(9, 1))
            Set c = .Find(Cells(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
                Else: Cells(i, 2) = "N/A"
                End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I do not need duplicates, but also I need the output in a new column, it should not change the values in the same column

Comment: Then instead compare the first column to the dict keys to see if they `.Exists` See update.

Comment: Sure I will try the same and will post you the outcome

Comment: Hi, @Raystafarian it gives me the output like this
**Oracle                         N/A
 java                                 java
 jsp                                 N/A
 javascript                 N/A
 .net                                 N/A
 manageral services N/A
 java                                 N/A**
Then I just removed the `not` from `If Not c Is Nothing Then` then it worked out

Comment: Yeah, I guess looking at it now the `not` isn't correct

Comment: To clarify, in my haze I **incorrectly** rejected your improvement suggestion on the post and there's no way I can undo that, so I apologize.

Comment: Thats fyn mate. Below is the improved version of the same with variable inputs and column suggestions **`Sub FilterUnique() Dim i As Long Dim j As LongDim c As RangeDim rowRange As VariantrowRange = InputBox("Enter Row Range?")Dim colNo As VariantcolNo = InputBox("Enter Column No to be processed ?")colNo = colNo - 1For i = 2 To rowRange+1With Range(Cells(i + 1, colNo + 1), Cells(rowRange + 1, colNo + 1))Set c = .Find(Cells(i, colNo + 1),LookIn:=xlValues)If Not c Is Nothing ThenCells(i, colNo + 2) = " "Else: Cells(i,colNo + 2) = Cells(i, colNo + 1)End IfEnd WithNext End Sub`**